# Referencing macOS SDK header is not resolving when compiling with clang

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to link my Rust library with a macOS SDK. When trying to include a header from a macOS SDK in an `.m` file and compiling, the linker returns an error.

Code example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <IOKit/KextManager.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Something");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> main.m:11:9: fatal error: 'IOKit/KextManager.h' file not found
>
> `#import <IOKit/KextManager.h>`
>
> ```
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
> ```

When I reference the full path, the header gets included but I get other linker errors for some classes not found:

Code example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/kext/KextManager.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Something");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_NSLog", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main-891267.o   "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
>         CFString in main-891267.o   "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
>         _main in main-891267.o   "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
>         _main in main-891267.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I suspect this is because other headers are not resolved properly.

How to make headers resolving to work properly so all includes work not only from Xcode?

This code compiles and runs directly from Xcode without any additional references but is not compiling from terminal:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/kext/KextManager.h"
//#import <IOKit/KextManager.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        CFDictionaryRef result = KextManagerCopyLoadedKextInfo(NULL, NULL);

        NSLog(@"%@", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Getting same linker error:

> ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib) built for (unknown). Note: This will be an
>   error in the future. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_KextManagerCopyLoadedKextInfo", referenced from:
>         _main in main-abff3c.o   "_NSLog", referenced from:
>         _main in main-abff3c.o   "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
>         CFString in main-abff3c.o   "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
>         _main in main-abff3c.o   "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
>         _main in main-abff3c.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Update 2:

Compiler command:

> clang -framework IOKit -framework Foundation main.m -o main

Works with full path to header, but does not for `#include <IOKit/KextManager.h>`

Comment: This has nothing to do with rust.

Comment: maybe someone experienced similar issues using rust-bindgen on Mac...

Comment: Seems like *including the compiler / linker commands* would be vitally important for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: @Shepmaster so your question partialy solved the issue, when compiled with `clang -framework IOKit -framework Foundation main.m -o main` command - it compiles ok. Now need to make bindgen to include those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to link Xcode included frameworks into include folder.

For stable release:

> ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/ /usr/local/include/

And for Xcode beta:

> ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/
>   /usr/local/include/

Then KextManager imported like this:

`#import <IOKit/kext/KextManager.h>`